# FragmentStatePagerAdapter add and remove item

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

After lot of research in stack overflow and google developer group i am not finding any good solution how i can add or remove Fragment form FragmentStatePagerAdapter (run time). My FragmentStatePagerAdapter is used in view pager.

Comment: I think you want to ad or remove fragments . first clear all backStack then  Change the adapter dataset and notify the adapter

Comment: yes i want to remove and add fragments. i have like a ,b, c, d,e,f , e fragment  "b"  fragment have some question and user can fill the question and user ans depend c ,d fragment will be need or no need. if need then it will be show if no need then i want to remove . the app also need to show indicator and user can go previous fragment and he can see which question he fill so adapter and view pager is need .

Comment: Do all validation at very first like how many fragments are needed . and set adapter only once. removing and adding is not a very good programming .

Comment: Validation depends on runtime according to user input .